# How do I ensure that the value of a property is one of the value in an pre-defined object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I am using React with TypeScript and would like to have to make sure the state type be limited to the values in an object like so.

Consider

```
 const [proessStatus, setProcessStatus] = useState<ProcessState>();
```

The useState must accept as argument only the values from the ProcessState Object.

```
const ProcessState = {
    NOT_STARTED: 'NOT_STARTED',
    STARTED: 'STARTED',
    LOADING: 'LOADING',
    FINISHED: 'FINISHED'
}
```

Is there a way to ensure this in TypeScript through Interfaces or any other means?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use string-based enums please!

```
enum ProcessState {
  NOT_STARTED = 'NOT_STARTED',
  STARTED = 'STARTED',
  LOADING = 'LOADING',
  FINISHED = 'FINISHED'  
}
```

They are type-safe in their values (so validation happens at compile time). You can use the Enum object itself as a normal object at runtime. If you need additional runtime validation you can use `Object.values(ProcessState)` to get the valid values. And you can use it with the `Record<SomeEnum, SomeValueType>` type to create type safe maps etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use enum and use it as the type of the argument of the function

```
enum ProcessState {
  NOT_STARTED = 'NOT_STARTED',
  STARTED = 'STARTED',
  LOADING = 'LOADING',
  FINISHED = 'FINISHED'  
}

function useState(p: ProcessState) {

   ...

}

useState(ProcessState.STARTED)
```

Comment: can I restrict it when I intialize state like ```const [pstate, setPstate] = useState<ProcessState>(ProcessState.STARTED);``` that was one of my main requirements..